# BeginTransaction Hibernate necessary?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

Is it really necessary to start a transaction when you are going to execute only one query, without deleting or updating data?

I'm currently using Hibernate 4.1.9 with C3p0

Example,

```
session session = hibernateutil.getsessionfactory().opensession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
List messages = session.createQuery("from Message m order by m.text asc").list();  
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation) says:

> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are **always necessary**. No communication with the database can occur outside of a database transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the auto-commit mode). **Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for read-only operations**. Depending on your isolation level and database capabilities this might not be required, but there is no downside if you always demarcate transactions explicitly. Certainly, a single database transaction is going to perform better than many small transactions, even for reading data.

(emphasis mine)